# How to use Inf with lubridate and dplyr case_when

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I want to build a custom function which returns a date x years ago, or in the case the x supplied is infinite, reverts to a special date. I'm using `dplyr` and `lubridate`. Here is a trivial example:

```
foo <- function(years_ago) {
    case_when(
        years_ago == Inf ~ as.Date("1800-01-01"),
        TRUE ~ Sys.Date() - years(years_ago)
    )
}
```

`foo(1)` duly returns the date 1 year ago. However, `foo(Inf)` gives me the error:
`argument is not interpretable as logical`. It seems that R jumps to evaluate the TRUE line of the case_when statement, even when the first condition is met.

Is there any way I can get these tidyverse functions to play nicely, or do I need to find a workaround in base R?

Comment: You are missing a comma after the first line in case_when.

Comment: Apart from that I recommend using the `is.infinite` function instead of `== Inf`.

Comment: Ah thanks - fixed the comma (this was in my original code!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case_when` always evaluates both conditions. So while it would be intuitive to assume that if your value is `Inf`, the case when would not evaluate the second line, it actually does. And then the problem is that the `years` function can't handle infinite values.

What you could do in the case_when, is to simply add an ifelse command that makes sure the years function is only run on values that are not infinite.

```
foo <- function(years_ago) {
  case_when(
    years_ago == Inf ~ as.Date("1800-01-01"),
    TRUE ~ Sys.Date() - years(ifelse(is.infinite(years_ago), 0, years_ago))
  )
}
```

Some examples:

```
foo(1)
[1] "2021-06-24"

foo(Inf)
[1] "1800-01-01"

foo(0)
[1] "2022-06-24"
```

Comment: I liked the elegance of this solution, but I found a problem with it: the ifelse statement was just returning zero even when years_ago was a finite value. You can try `ifelse(is.infinite(1), years(1), years(2))` - it just yields 0. Very odd behaviour... I managed to make it work by substituting dplyr if_else i.e. substituting `if_else(is.infinite(years_ago), years(0), years(years_ago))`. Would be great if you could update the answer

Comment: Actually this doesn't work: my version suffers from the same problem as the original statement when `years_ago == Inf` :-(

Comment: Please see my update. Works fine for me in case of `Inf`. If it doesn't work for you, please provide some example data to work with.

Comment: Also FYI on the weird behaviour of ifelse: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72749363/ifelse-command-always-returns-0-if-condition-contains-years-function-from-pack I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ah brilliant - yes this works perfectly - and is my preferred solution :-) Thanks (& sorry it's taken me a while to get back to this)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a pretty solution, but I think this works? Not sure why testing for `Inf` with `is.infinite` within the `case_when` also fails though as that was my first thought.

```
foo <- function(years_ago) {
  if (is.infinite(years_ago)) {
    years_ago <- NA
  }
  
  case_when(
    is.finite(years_ago) ~ Sys.Date() - years(years_ago),
    is.na(years_ago) ~ as.Date("1800-01-01"),
  )
}
```

Alternatively, given the above already carries out the logical statement as part of the "if", then the following should also work?

```
foo <- function(years_ago) {
  if (is.infinite(years_ago)) {
    rtrn <- as.Date("1800-01-01")
  } else {
    rtrn <- Sys.Date() - years(years_ago)
  }
  rtrn
}
```

Comment: From all this I've concluded that there's no alternative to using the base `if`, `else` family of statements. `case_when`, `if_else`, `ifelse`, `fifelse` etc. all result in some VERY unusual behaviour of one sort or another...