# ifelse command always returns 0 if condition contains `years` function from package lubridate

Tags: r, if-statement, lubridate

I have an ifelse condition where I want to return a `years` value from package lubridate.

However, it does return 0 inside the ifelse and I have no idea why.

```
library(lubridate)

years(1)

[1] "1y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S" # correct

years(2)

[1] "2y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S" # correct

ifelse(1 == 1, years(1), years(2))

[1] 0 # wrong
```

Can anyone explain why the ifelse returns 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is why it happens. This is from the bottom of source code of `ifelse`, which will run in your example.

```r
ans <- test
len <- length(ans)
ypos <- which(test)
npos <- which(!test)
if (length(ypos) > 0L) 
  ans[ypos] <- rep(yes, length.out = len)[ypos]
if (length(npos) > 0L) 
  ans[npos] <- rep(no, length.out = len)[npos]
ans
```

The function is modifying the `ans` vector by element, not the entire vector itself. So therefore the attributes from `yes` and `no` are being dropped.

```r
ans <- TRUE
ans[1] <- years(1)

ans
# [1] 0
```

Below is from the the help file. The "mode of the answer will be coerced from logical" starting with the `yes` values first.

```r
mode(years(1))
# [1] "numeric"
```

> **Value**
>
> A vector of the same length and attributes (including dimensions and
> "class") as test and data values from the values of yes or no. The
> mode of the answer will be coerced from logical to accommodate first
> any values taken from yes and then any values taken from no.

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way it constructs its output, `ifelse` strips the attributes from a vector. This is not unique to `lubridate::year`. It also happens with, for example, dates and date-times

```r
ifelse(1 == 1, as.Date("2022-06-24"), as.Date("2022-06-25"))
#> [1] 19167
```

Using `dplyr::if_else` avoids this problem:

```r
dplyr::if_else(1 == 1, years(1), years(2))
#> [1] "1y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```

And obviously the low-tech fix is to do:

```r
years(ifelse(1 == 1, 1, 2))
#> [1] "1y 0m 0d 0H 0M 0S"
```